# Laravel 8 - Custom attributes of component giving error: Unresolvable dependency resolving

Tags: laravel

I am trying to pass some text data to component like this

```
<x-header title="{{$product->page_title}}" desc="{{$product->page_des}}" keywords="{{$product->keywords}}" />
```

And did this in `view/component -> header.php`

```
public $title;
public $desc;
public $keywords;
public function __construct($title, $desc, $keywords)
{
    $this->title = $title;
    $this->desc = $desc;
    $this->keywords = $keywords;
}
```

And finally calling data in `view -> components -> header.blade.php` like this

```
<title>{{$title}}</title>
<meta name="description" content="{{$desc}}">
<meta name="keywords" content="{{$keywords}}">
```

But it is giving me this error

```
Unresolvable dependency resolving [Parameter #0 [ <required> $title ]] in class App\View\Components\header (View: D:\xampp\htdocs\elab\resources\views\productDetail.blade.php)
```

Any idea, where I went wrong here?

Comment: try clearing cache .php artisan view:clear or php artisan optimize

Comment: @JohnLobo Thanks for the response, it was my mistake in code. I found it ^^

Answer (score -1):

Okay resolved it, it was my dumb mistake.

Actually I was calling my header component like this earlier.

```
<x-header />
```

Later decided to upgrade it with metas and added this

```
<x-header title="{{$product->page_title}}" desc="{{$product->page_des}}" keywords="{{$product->keywords}}" />
```

But forgot to remove previously added `<x-header />`. When it runs then it was searching for attribute value which was missing coz it was running empty header component `<x-header />` first.

Sorry for inconvenience.